# Can't bind textbox to object. DataBindings property not available

Tags: c#, wpf

(I'm new to WPF)
I have as objects with severals properties which I would like to bind to textbox.
I have a textbox control named txtStudentName.
looking for some examples got me think I need to use the next method:

$txtStudentName.DataBindings.Add(,,);

But I don't have the DataBindings property in my textbox object.

anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bind like this:

```
TextBox MyText = new TextBox();

Binding binding = new Binding();
binding.Path = new PropertyPath("Name"); //Name of the property in Datacontext
BindingOperations.SetBinding(MyText,TextBox.TextProperty , binding);
```

If you want to bind to certain object which contains Name property you will have to set binding.Source to that object also.

Comment: What is the name of the property in Datacontext? I have an object named Studnet with the property studentName. I want to bind it... student.studnentName

Comment: In PropertyPath("") you have to give name of the property in datacontext or binding.Source of textbox

Comment: How do I define datacontext? Is this an object? I dont know what it is

Comment: can u share which proprty u want to bind...?

Comment: public string firstName
        {
            get { return _firstName; }
            set
            {
                if (value != _firstName)
                {
                    _firstName = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("_firstName");
                }
            }
        }

Comment: Every object that descends from `FrameworkElement` has a property called `DataContext`.  This is a reference to an object that represents the default source of data for any bindings you write in your XAML.  You can put any object you want into the `DataContext` property of any control defined in your XAML.  If you don't specify a source for the property in any binding, WPF will check that control's `DataContext`; if it doesn't have one, it checks that control's parent, and so on up the visual tree until it either finds one or there are none left.

Comment: well actually you should be using mvvm and bind the property in xaml as others has answered. But just to solve you query if you want to do it in code behind, in my answer do binding.Path = new PropertyPath("firstName") and Set binding.Source = (the object containing firstName)

Comment: Tony, Thanks for the detailed answert. nit, thanks to you also. It solved the problem!

Comment: Another question. Now when i'm assign a different value for my object (the one I defined as my window datacontext) it won't change the binding. I.E the textbox value does not changes...

Comment: bro i will need to see you complete code to see what you have set as DataContext of window and what you are setting for textbox..

Comment: public MainWindow()
        {
            try
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                Classes.studentManager stdManager = new Classes.studentManager();
                studentsList = stdManager.Select();

                this.dgStudents.DataContext = studentsList;

                selectedStudent = studentsList[0];
                this.DataContext = selectedStudent;
                
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }    the last line (this.DataContext = selectedStudent;)

Comment: Here i'm changing the object value           private void dgStudents_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            selectedStudent = new student();
            selectedStudent = (student)dgStudents.SelectedItem;
        }

Comment: it wont work.. i will suggest you to create the properties for SelectedStudent, StudentList in your window and implement IPropertyChanged for your window like you did for other class. Now in constructor of you window do this.DataContext = this. Now you will have all the properties in windows datacontext and you can directly bind in xaml

Answer (score 2):

You can also bind in the XAML, if the objects you want to bind to are public and are properties of the object in your data context:

```
<Window x:Class="CarSystem.AlarmsDialog"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        DataContext="{Binding MyDataContextObject, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
        Title="LPR - Mobile Plate Hunter 900: Alarms">

    <Grid>
        <TextBox Text={Binding Path=MyTextProperty, Mode=TwoWay} />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged WPF, consider doing this in XAML only:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=SomeTextProperty, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

Comment: This is exactly what I want to do. How do I use my object in the XAML part? (I'm new to WPF)

Comment: @ShaulZuarets If you have a single object Person with a string property Name, you can do {Binding Path=Person.Name}. In the codebehind of the XAML, its .cs file, you can assign the this.DataContext to the class that has all the properties you'll want to utilize. MVVM is a common practice of this and a good learning route, I suggest this walk-through: http://karlshifflett.wordpress.com/2010/11/07/in-the-box-ndash-mvvm-training/